# scrapy - error in settings that does not allow me to do anything with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-settings

I accidentally changed something in my `scrapy` settings (I was trying to `debug` a spider by creating a `runner.py` file), and I can't do anything now with scrapy. This is the error I am getting after running **any** `scrapy` related command in the command prompt:

```
(scrape_virtual_workspace) C:\Users\Sophocles PC>cd projects

(scrape_virtual_workspace) C:\Users\Sophocles PC\projects>scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\scrape_virtual_workspace\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\scrape_virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 117, in execute
    check_deprecated_settings(settings)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\scrape_virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\deprecated.py", line 22, in check_deprecated_settings
    deprecated = [x for x in DEPRECATED_SETTINGS if settings.get(x[0], None) is not None]
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\scrape_virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\deprecated.py", line 22, in <listcomp>
    deprecated = [x for x in DEPRECATED_SETTINGS if settings.get(x[0], None) is not None]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

(scrape_virtual_workspace) C:\Users\Sophocles PC\projects>
```

I tried fiddling with settings to correct this. But I can't seem to figure it out.

Can anyone help me with this?

below you can see **deprecated.py**:

```
import warnings
from scrapy.exceptions import ScrapyDeprecationWarning

DEPRECATED_SETTINGS = [
    ('TRACK_REFS', 'no longer needed (trackref is always enabled)'),
    ('RESPONSE_CLASSES', 'no longer supported'),
    ('DEFAULT_RESPONSE_ENCODING', 'no longer supported'),
    ('BOT_VERSION', 'no longer used (user agent defaults to Scrapy now)'),
    ('ENCODING_ALIASES', 'no longer needed (encoding discovery uses w3lib now)'),
    ('STATS_ENABLED', 'no longer supported (change STATS_CLASS instead)'),
    ('SQLITE_DB', 'no longer supported'),
    ('SELECTORS_BACKEND', 'use SCRAPY_SELECTORS_BACKEND environment variable instead'),
    ('AUTOTHROTTLE_MIN_DOWNLOAD_DELAY', 'use DOWNLOAD_DELAY instead'),
    ('AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_CONCURRENCY', 'use CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN instead'),
    ('AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_CONCURRENCY', 'use CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN instead'),
    ('REDIRECT_MAX_METAREFRESH_DELAY', 'use METAREFRESH_MAXDELAY instead'),
    ('LOG_UNSERIALIZABLE_REQUESTS', 'use SCHEDULER_DEBUG instead'),
]


def check_deprecated_settings(settings):
    deprecated = [x for x in DEPRECATED_SETTINGS if settings[x[0]] is not None]
    if deprecated:
        msg = "You are using the following settings which are deprecated or obsolete"
        msg += " (ask scrapy-users@googlegroups.com for alternatives):"
        msg = msg + "\n    " + "\n    ".join("%s: %s" % x for x in deprecated)
        warnings.warn(msg, ScrapyDeprecationWarning)
```

below you can see **settings.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Scrapy settings for zalando project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'zalando'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['zalando.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'zalando.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
#DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
#COOKIES_ENABLED = False

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
#TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
#DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en',
#}

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'zalando.middlewares.ZalandoSpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'zalando.middlewares.NetAPorterMaleDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
#}


# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html

# Enable or disable extensions
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
#EXTENSIONS = {
#    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
#}

# Configure item pipelines
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
#ITEM_PIPELINES = {
#    'za
# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
#AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
#AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
#AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
#AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
#AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)lando.pipelines.ZalandoPipeline': 300,
#}

# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
#HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
#HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
#HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
#HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
#HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'
```

** scrapy-script.py"" file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from scrapy.cmdline import execute

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(execute())
```

**cmdline.py**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys, os
import optparse
import cProfile
import inspect
import pkg_resources

import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.commands import ScrapyCommand
from scrapy.exceptions import UsageError
from scrapy.utils.misc import walk_modules
from scrapy.utils.project import inside_project, get_project_settings
from scrapy.utils.python import garbage_collect
from scrapy.settings.deprecated import check_deprecated_settings

def _iter_command_classes(module_name):
    # TODO: add `name` attribute to commands and and merge this function with
    # scrapy.utils.spider.iter_spider_classes
    for module in walk_modules(module_name):
        for obj in vars(module).values():
            if inspect.isclass(obj) and \
                    issubclass(obj, ScrapyCommand) and \
                    obj.__module__ == module.__name__ and \
                    not obj == ScrapyCommand:
                yield obj

def _get_commands_from_module(module, inproject):
    d = {}
    for cmd in _iter_command_classes(module):
        if inproject or not cmd.requires_project:
            cmdname = cmd.__module__.split('.')[-1]
            d[cmdname] = cmd()
    return d

def _get_commands_from_entry_points(inproject, group='scrapy.commands'):
    cmds = {}
    for entry_point in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points(group):
        obj = entry_point.load()
        if inspect.isclass(obj):
            cmds[entry_point.name] = obj()
        else:
            raise Exception("Invalid entry point %s" % entry_point.name)
    return cmds

def _get_commands_dict(settings, inproject):
    cmds = _get_commands_from_module('scrapy.commands', inproject)
    cmds.update(_get_commands_from_entry_points(inproject))
    cmds_module = settings['COMMANDS_MODULE']
    if cmds_module:
        cmds.update(_get_commands_from_module(cmds_module, inproject))
    return cmds

def _pop_command_name(argv):
    i = 0
    for arg in argv[1:]:
        if not arg.startswith('-'):
            del argv[i]
            return arg
        i += 1

def _print_header(settings, inproject):
    if inproject:
        print("Scrapy %s - project: %s\n" % (scrapy.__version__, \
            settings['BOT_NAME']))
    else:
        print("Scrapy %s - no active project\n" % scrapy.__version__)

def _print_commands(settings, inproject):
    _print_header(settings, inproject)
    print("Usage:")
    print("  scrapy <command> [options] [args]\n")
    print("Available commands:")
    cmds = _get_commands_dict(settings, inproject)
    for cmdname, cmdclass in sorted(cmds.items()):
        print("  %-13s %s" % (cmdname, cmdclass.short_desc()))
    if not inproject:
        print()
        print("  [ more ]      More commands available when run from project directory")
    print()
    print('Use "scrapy <command> -h" to see more info about a command')

def _print_unknown_command(settings, cmdname, inproject):
    _print_header(settings, inproject)
    print("Unknown command: %s\n" % cmdname)
    print('Use "scrapy" to see available commands')

def _run_print_help(parser, func, *a, **kw):
    try:
        func(*a, **kw)
    except UsageError as e:
        if str(e):
            parser.error(str(e))
        if e.print_help:
            parser.print_help()
        sys.exit(2)

def execute(argv=None, settings=None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv

    # --- backwards compatibility for scrapy.conf.settings singleton ---
    if settings is None and 'scrapy.conf' in sys.modules:
        from scrapy import conf
        if hasattr(conf, 'settings'):
            settings = conf.settings
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------

    if settings is None:
        settings = get_project_settings()
        # set EDITOR from environment if available
        try:
            editor = os.environ['EDITOR']
        except KeyError: pass
        else:
            settings['EDITOR'] = editor
    check_deprecated_settings(settings)

    # --- backwards compatibility for scrapy.conf.settings singleton ---
    import warnings
    from scrapy.exceptions import ScrapyDeprecationWarning
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore", ScrapyDeprecationWarning)
        from scrapy import conf
        conf.settings = settings
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------

    inproject = inside_project()
    cmds = _get_commands_dict(settings, inproject)
    cmdname = _pop_command_name(argv)
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(formatter=optparse.TitledHelpFormatter(), \
        conflict_handler='resolve')
    if not cmdname:
        _print_commands(settings, inproject)
        sys.exit(0)
    elif cmdname not in cmds:
        _print_unknown_command(settings, cmdname, inproject)
        sys.exit(2)

    cmd = cmds[cmdname]
    parser.usage = "scrapy %s %s" % (cmdname, cmd.syntax())
    parser.description = cmd.long_desc()
    settings.setdict(cmd.default_settings, priority='command')
    cmd.settings = settings
    cmd.add_options(parser)
    opts, args = parser.parse_args(args=argv[1:])
    _run_print_help(parser, cmd.process_options, args, opts)

    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
    sys.exit(cmd.exitcode)

def _run_command(cmd, args, opts):
    if opts.profile:
        _run_command_profiled(cmd, args, opts)
    else:
        cmd.run(args, opts)

def _run_command_profiled(cmd, args, opts):
    if opts.profile:
        sys.stderr.write("scrapy: writing cProfile stats to %r\n" % opts.profile)
    loc = locals()
    p = cProfile.Profile()
    p.runctx('cmd.run(args, opts)', globals(), loc)
    if opts.profile:
        p.dump_stats(opts.profile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        execute()
    finally:
        # Twisted prints errors in DebugInfo.__del__, but PyPy does not run gc.collect()
        # on exit: http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/cpython_differences.html?highlight=gc.collect#differences-related-to-garbage-collection-strategies
        garbage_collect()
``


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELQdK.png
```

Comment: Can you share the settings.py as well as `DEPRECATED_SETTINGS`? Or just try to cross-reference those yourself.

Comment: Just did. By the way, this error started appearing when i tried to create a ```runner.py``` and in that I tried to overrun the ```get_project_settings()``` in an effort to debug my spider. Let me know if you want me to share anything else.

Comment: Hmm from where are you calling `check_deprecated_settings` and what are you using as the `settings` argument value? Might be a problem there. Otherwise you might need to change the `settings[x[0]]` to `settings.get(x[0], None)`

Comment: I tried to change the settings to ```settings.get(x[0], None)```, but I get the same error unfortunately.

Comment: I added the ```if settings is None:``` part of the **cmdline** if you want to check it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded my `scrapy` version to 1.5.2, and somehow it worked.  This is very strange and it seems to me that the newer versions have removed a couple of files (like deprecated.py). This was very annoying.